# UIPickerViewDelegate rowHeightForComponent returns an out of bounds index

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm writing a code with a UIPickerView that has 3 components. I want each component to have a different row height. I have an array of model components, each has the property `rowHeight` and I implemented `pickerView(_:rowHeightForComponent:)` as the following:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
  components[component].rowHeight
}
```

but it turns out that the parameter `component` sometimes equals to the number of components, i.e. in my case is sometimes equals 3. So I actually get a component index that is out of bounds. Did anyone have the same problem? Is it a known bug?

Comment: This doesn't happen "on its own." Something in your code is causing the issue. Are you *sure* `component` equals `3` when you get the error? Or, is it possible you've told the picker view that it has 3 components, but your `components[]` array only has 1 or 2? Put together a simple [mre] and we can review / test  your code.

Comment: For sure, in the debugger the value of `component` is 3.

Comment: Also, in the UIPickerViewDataSource the implementation of `numberOfComponents(in:)` is simply `3`.

Comment: Did you check and it doesn't happen to you?

Comment: After quick testing, couple notes: 1) `rowHeightForComponent` ***is*** called one-too-many times. 2) PickerView will use the ***largest*** value returned for all components. 3) Font is not applied when implementing `attributedTitleForRow`. 4) If you want 3 "columns" with differing row heights, it looks like you'll need 3 single-component picker views.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of 2 and 4.